# Search one array element with another

Tags: postgresql, array

I have got tables:

```
children_tab
id
name
lastname

parent_tab
id
name
lastname

children_parent_tab
children_id
parent_id
```

There is also parent view that return in field children_ids elements from children_parent_tab

I have to search parents by children ids

Let's say that parent contain:

```
1|name1|lastname1|{1}
2|name2|lastname2|{5}
3|name3|lastname3|{3,7}

SELECT * FROM parent p WHERE ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::int[]  @> children_ids
```

will return only parent with id 1 and 2 but without that one with id 3. How that query can be changed to return also parent with id 3 because I'm looking for parent of child with id 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to run the query on the view. Should be substantially faster based on underlying tables. Like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent_id
FROM   children_parent_tab
WHERE  children_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::int[]);
```

Details depend on undisclosed exact table definitions and requirements.

Be that as it may, you can fix the query you presented with the ["overlap" operator **`&&`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) instead of the "contains" operator `@>`:

```
SELECT * FROM parent p WHERE ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::int[] && children_ids;
```

This way you get all parents of any of the children in the given array.

Comment: Thanks, && made a job